# Vector of Vectors on C

Tags: c, vector

I'm new here and this is my first question, i couldn't find anything like this in the search engine so my problem is basically a vector of vectors on C, here is what i have done until now but i keep getting a deadly warning, so i know that I'm not using well the structure with the vector and I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks

PD: Sorry for my english.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
int n;
int *vector;
}Vector_T;

int inicializar_original(int *n,int dim)
{
int i,r,s,j,*k;
Vector_T *t;
Vector_T l;
srand(time(NULL));
r=rand()%10;
scanf("%d",&s);
t->vector=k;
l.n=s;
k=(int*)malloc(s*sizeof(int));
for(j=0;j<s;j++)
{
k[j]=r;
}
    for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
    n[i]=k;
    }
}


int main()
{
int *v,dim;
scanf("%d",&dim);
v=(int*)malloc(dim*sizeof(int));
inicializar_original(v,dim);
}
```

Comment: First, please format your code; as it is now, it's very difficult to read. Second, what is the error, and on which line is it happening? What have you done to try to fix the error?

Comment: 0) `t->vector=k;` , `t` and `k` are not initialize. 1) `n[i]=k;` lvalue is `int`. rvalue is `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que hablas español, así que aquí va: El problema más grande es que no estás inicializando la variable "k". Mi sugerencia es que intentes lo siguente:

```
int i,r,s,j;
int* k;
```

If English only: Your problem is probably that you're initializing K in the wrong way. Try to do:

```
int i,r,s,j;
int* k;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    int n;
    int *vector;
}Vector_T;

int inicializar_original(Vector_T *v, int dim){
    int i, j, s, r = rand()%10;

    scanf("%d", &s);
    for(i=0; i<dim; i++){
        int *k = malloc( s * sizeof(int));
        for(j=0; j<s; j++){
            k[j]=r;
        }
        v[i].n = s;
        v[i].vector = k;
    }
}


int main(void){
    Vector_T *v;
    int dim;

    srand(time(NULL));
    scanf("%d", &dim);
    v = malloc(dim * sizeof(*v));
    inicializar_original(v, dim);

    { //check print & release
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < dim; ++i){
            for(j = 0; j < v[i].n ; ++j){
                printf("%d ", v[i].vector[j]);
            }
            puts("");
            free(v[i].vector);
        }
        free(v);
    }

    return 0;
}
```